# ASP.NET dynamically add column to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can I add to GridView dynamically some columns based on condition?

```
  <asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
    datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
    autogeneratecolumns="true"
    emptydatatext="No data available." 
    runat="server">

    <columns>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerID" headertext="Customer ID"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName" headertext="Company Name"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="Address" headertext="Address"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="City" headertext="City"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="PostalCode" headertext="Postal Code"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="Country" headertext="Country"/>
    </columns>
    for(int i; i < length; i++)
      <asp:boundfield datafield="text" headertext="text"/>
  </asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
BoundField test = new BoundField();
test.DataField = "New DATAfield Name";
test.Headertext = "New Header";
CustomersGridView.Columns.Add(test);
```

Comment: @uuser3305953 - To use above code, you should first make autogeneratecolumns="false"

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

First set the property of your GridView `yourGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false` then add following code to server side:

```cs
BoundField newColumn = new BoundField();

newColumn.DataField = "New DATAfield Name";
newColumn.HeaderText = "New Header";

yourGridView.Columns.Add(newColumn);
```

Note: Here `newColumn` is your Dynamic Column that you want to add, and `yourGridView` is your GridView name