# How to add column manually in aspx.net based on a condition

Tags: asp.net

```
<%if (Session[Global.SYSTEM_NAME].ToString().Contains("Coco Cola")){%>   
  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Image" HeaderStyle-Width="170" Reorderable="false" Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>                        
      <center>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"
                        Height="145" Width="160" AlternateText="Signature preview not available"
                        src='<%# "Data:BASE64VALUE/png;base64," + Eval("BASE64VALUE") %>'/>
```

Here I am trying to add grid template column only for coco cola. I am unable to add if condition there. Can any one help me on this?

Comment: You cannot add column inlines like that. You need to do that in code behind.

Comment: how to add a condition in code behind

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754144/asp-net-dynamically-add-column-to-gridview/21755678

Comment: since i need both auto generated columns and manually added columns above article is not a solution for me

Comment: Could you maybe just have the column render regardless and then have the content for that column be empty if it doesn't meet your condition?